# Prevent complete recompilation in visual studio when copying projects

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2013

I switch a lot between my laptop and my home PC when working with visual studio, but every time I copy a project between them, visual studio wants to recompile the entire thing because it thinks the files have changed.

This can take quite a bit of time for larger projects, so I was wondering if there was a way to tell visual studio that everything is already 'up to date' and doesn't need recompilation. (Except if files are changed after that point of course.)

(I don't have an external hard drive)

Comment: Another (IMHO much better) option is to use a VCS.

Comment: You mean `Build > cancel` to stop compiling? Or just `ctrl+Break`.